# How to generate specific data from webpage?

Tags: php

I trying using php to get the data from a webpage, anyone can show me a tutorial to get the data from a specific page?

Example data source:
http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/4d/Pages/Results.aspx

Can I use php to generate the result then save it into a database?

Comment: You are thinking of a web crawler, you can use pretty much any language you want (including PHP)

Comment: @Ah dii was my answer correct? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $HTML = File_get_contents("http://www.singaporepools.com.sg/en/4d/Pages/Results.aspx");
```

This will load the html of the page to a string called $HTML.

Comment: Can I just gather some information from the page? Because the code is displaying the whole webpage and incomplete.

Comment: Displaying? The code should not display it, it should only save it to the string variable. What information are you looking for in the code.

Comment: @Ah dii, as above? Displaying??